# Написание сокращённой формы названий министерств

Tags: орфография

Министерства в сокращенном варианте, типа "минюст", "минздрав", "совмин" - пишутся с большой буквы или с маленькой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По факту - везде с заглавной. Минюст, Минздрав и т.д. 
Но боюсь, это не совсем соответствует духу и букве существующих орфографических правил.

===

Кстати, имейте в виду, что это касается только российских министерств. В отношении зарубежных министерств наблюдается значительный разнобой. Я так полагаю, там всё-таки со строчной.

Answer (score 0):

Соответствует. В правилах русской орфографии (РАН) приводится именно такое написание

Comment: Да, я знаю.
Но это что-то типа "дополнения к закону", как говорят юристы.
Смысл подобного мне не ясен, если не считать давления чиновников. Колхоз не пишется с заглавной? А чем Минюст лучше?

Comment: Ну, "коллективное хозяйство" пишется с маленькой, поэтому и колхоз тоже. "Министерство" принято писать с большой - и Минюст поэтому тоже. А уж тут дело традиции.

Answer (score 0):

Указанные слова являются т.н. сложносокращёнными названиями. Это значит, что исходные слова не свёрнуты до одной буквы. Согласно правилам, такие сокращения следует писать так: первая буква прописная, остальные - строчные. Но иногда бывает так, что некоторые слова исходного названия сворачиваются до одной буквы (на манер аббревиатуры). В этом случае сокращение считается смешанным. При таком сокращении аббревиатурная часть пишется прописными, а более сложная часть - так, как и сложное сокращение. Если бы Научно-Исследовательский Институт Химических Удобрений и Ядов из анекдота существовал в действительности, то его бы не стали сокращать до аббревиатуры, а придумали бы что-нибудь более приличное. НИИХимудобрений, например...

Comment: Нет таких правил.  
Насчет "сворачиваются до одной буквы" - нет, я столько не выпью.

Comment: Вы правы. В правилах это сформулировано иначе.

Comment: Да бог с ними, с правилами. Своими словами вашу мысль можно выразить без подобных умслопогасов?!

Comment: Уверен, вы и в этом правы.

Comment: И я уверен.